# Winter 18' release and Service Cloud Toolkit API cannot be used with your browser

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

When I try to use any of the workspace API javascript Library features now that winter 18' has been released for salesforce lightning, I get the following error when trying to open a subtab:

```
workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
        var tabId = response.tabId;
        var ptabid = tabId.split('_');

        workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
            parentTabId: ptabid[0],
            url: '/one/one.app?source=aloha#' + strBase64,
            focus: true
        });
    });
```

in the console: "uncaught exception: Error: Could not locate focused tab."

FYI:  This code appeared to work in our sandbox pre final Winter 18" release.  It just started to break today (post Winter 18').

Anyone else having this issue?  Any help would be appreciated.